# How can you disable entry deletion when member account removed?

Tags: members, control-panel, entries, delete

My client deleted an admin (not super admin) account and it deleted all their posts. Is there a plugin or setting to stop this from happening and allows entries to be reassigned to another user account?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's already an option to reassign the entries created by that member to another member. It appears as a dropdown when you go through the deletion confirmation process.